# ошибка при заполнении матрицы

Tags: python, матрицы

пишу код для построение матрицы-улитка закручивающейся по часовой стрелке. Возник "invalid syntax"  в 16 строке, не понимаю в чем причина.

```
a=int(input())
b=a**2
mat1=[]
mat2=[[0 for i in  range(a)] for j in range(a)]
for x in range(b+1):
  mat1.append(x)
  cikl=[[0]]

  if mat2[cikl[0][0]][a-1]==0:#с лева на право
    mat2[0][x]+=(x+1) 
    if mat2[cikl[0][0]][a-1]!=0:
      continue
  shag=0

  if mat2[cikl[0][0]][a-1]!=0 and mat2[a-1-cikl[0][0][a-1-cikl[0][0]]==0:#сверху вниз


    !!!"mat2[1+shag][a-1-cikl[0][0]]+=x+1"!!!
    shag+=1
    if mat2[a-1-cikl[0][0]][a-1-cikl[0][0]]!=0:
      cikl[0][0]+=1
      continue

  if mat2[a-1-cikl[0][0]][a-1-cikl[0][0]]!=0 and mat2[a-cikl[0][0]][cikl[0][0]-1]==0:#с право на лево
    shag=0 
    mat2[a-1-cikl[0][0]][a-cikl[0][0]-shag]+=x+1
    shag+=1
    if mat2[a-cikl[0][0]][cikl[0][0]-1]!=0:
      continue
print(mat2)
```

Answer (score 0):

не хватает закрывающей скобки:

`if mat2[cikl[0][0]][a-1]!=0 and mat2[a-1-cikl[0][0]**]**[a-1-cikl[0][0]]==0:`сверху вниз